# PHP: Shopping Cart calculations malfunction

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mini shopping cart, Which updates the shopping cart in real time.
I have a item count for each time a item has been added into the cart, it adds one to the item count each time a item is added. I have been testing my cart and noticed the cart number count does not match the actual number of item in the cart, for example, if i have add 4 items to the cart, the number count will show  as 7.

I realised the number count starts at 3 instead instead of 0, After further investigation i realised that the item count is adding the restaurants id number to the number count, in this case the restaurant_id number is 3.

I have not used the restaurant id to create the number count, which is confusing,
i have tried misusing the restaurant id variable from the number count, but the count then starts of at -2 instead of 0.

How can i get my number count to start at 0?

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
$_SESSION['Shopping_cart_' . (int) $_GET['add_item']]+='1';
} 
function cart() {
if ($value > 0) {
     $runn_query = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_query);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($runn_query);
     while ....
         $item_sub = $get_row['Product_Price'] * $value;
     .....
        //creating subtotal

        $total += $sub_total ;
        ......

        echo "Items";
```

**What have i tried**

```
  $num_item += $value -=$_SESSION['rest_id']
```

and

```
if ($num_items ==0){
        echo "";

    }else{
    echo "$num_items";
    }
```

Pretty confused at the moment.

Comment: I can't even see when `$num_items` is declared.

Comment: ^^^ `$value` also (and many more). How about just set `$num_items = 0;` at the very first.

Comment: @Chay22 i just tried that before reading this and it will not update when set to 0

Comment: Your posted code doesn't tell what does `$num_items`, `$value`, (value of) `$_SESSION['rest_id']`, etc. This is unclear for me.

Comment: @Chay22 sorry. num_items = the number of items added to the cart. $_SESSION['rest_id'] = restaurant is and $value = the cost of each item

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you are posting. It is incomplete (and frankly not the cleanest I have seen). Why do you maintain a counter in the first place? Why not just count the number of items when you need them?

Comment: The first line of the function `if ($value > 0) {` questions me what's the value of it.

Comment: @Pevara it is a mini cart, so its calculates everything is real time, part of the brief is a real time item counter

Comment: @Chay22 the value is the number of items, e.g 2 x shirt